# How do I base64 decode something on the command line if the string contains new lines?

Tags: bash, base64, cygwin, decode

I'm using a Cygwin bash termianl if that matters.  I'm trying to base64 decode a file that has newlines within the base64 string.  Here's the last part of the string ...

```
...
RgBHAEgASQBKAEsCABIBABMFAQACABgCAAAaBAoASQBzAHMAdQBlAHIATgBhAG0AZQAcAB0AHgAf
ACAAIQAiACMAJBIBACYFAQACACkEAgAxADgCAAAsACEALhIBAAgFAQACAAsAHwANAA4ADwIAABEC
AAA7ACEAPQAdAD8AHQBBAB0AQwAdAgAARgBHAEgASQBKAEsCABIBABMFAQACABgCAAAaBBIAUwBl
AHQAdABsAGUAbQBlAG4AdABDAHUAcgByAGUAbgBjAHkAHAAdAB4AHwAgACEAIgAjACQSAQAmBQEA
AgApBAIAMQA5AgAALAAhAC4SAQAIBQEAAgALAB8ADQAOAA8CAAARAgAAOwAhAD0AHQA/AB0AQQAd
AEMAHQIAAEYARwBIAEkASgBLAgAAOwAhAD0AHQA/AB0CAAIAAgA=
```

Is there a way to decode a string with the new lines in it?  here's what I have tried so far ...

```
$ cat test.base64 | base64 --decode

com.wm.data.ISMemDataImbase64: invalid input
```

Comment: Maybe a line ending issue? File with Unix line endings and program expects windows ones or vis versa?

Comment: I don't think the `base64` you're running is the one from Cygwin. What you're showing is some error from a Java package `com.wm.data` which certainly has nothing to do with Cygwin. Check `which base64` and your `$PATH` environment variable.